# Diophantine Equation 1

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to solve for positive integral values of $x$ and $y$:
$$1216562x=87654321y+a$$
Here $a$ is a positive integer. For example if $a=40642509$ then one solution is : $x=37716$ and $y=523$

How do I proceed? I shall be grateful if anyone can help me.

Comment: Since $\gcd(40642509,87654321)=1$ the lemma of Bézout (cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity) ensures us that there exists $x$ and $y$ such that $1216562x-87654321y=1$. So multiplying with $a$ will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know the condition for existence of solution. But how can I find the smallest positive integral solutions for any positive integer $a$? Ok. Now I get it. Thanks. Can you please give the solution for $1216562x-87654321y=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Use the extended euclidean algorithm  :      Calculating the steps leading to the gcd backwards allows to find a linear
        combination 
$ax+by=c$, where c is the gcd, here $1$.

Example : $a=18 , b = 5$

$$18 = 5*3+3$$
$$5 = 3*1 + 2$$
$$3 = 2*1 + 1 $$

So, we have $$1=3-2 = 3-(5-3) = 2*3-5 = 2*(18-5*3)-5 = 2*18-7*5$$